# Blog posts not displaying on blog posts page

Tags: posts, query-posts

Not sure what's happening, but I just took over a site, and no blog posts are rendering on the blog index page. Posts are displaying on the home page but not the posts page. Any suggestions to what this might be? I disabled all plugins - no affect, also checked the database, which seems to be fine: http://ficdn.ca/fit-news/

Index.php

```
<?php if($blog_post_query->have_posts()): ?>
                        <?php while($blog_post_query->have_posts()): $blog_post_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <?php //get_template_part( 'template-content/content', 'blog' ); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="post" posts_per_page="5" scroll="false" transition="fade" button_label="Older Posts"]'); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-content/content', 'none' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

blog.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h2 class="entry-title">
    <?php if(!is_page('public-policy')) the_title(); ?>
</h2>
<p><?php post_info(); ?></p>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?> 
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: The html output of provided link contains a `<h1>` tag after the `<article>`, but your code contains a `<h2>` tag. Are you sure you are investigating the proper php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index.php is calling a template part (*template-content/content-blog.php*), which logically should contain the post content, but it's commented out.

**Change:**
`<?php //get_template_part( 'template-content/content', 'blog' ); ?>`

**To This:**
`<?php get_template_part( 'template-content/content', 'blog' ); ?>`

See if that helps.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Can't believe I didn't notice that. Cheers.